# How can I eliminate one 3-way switch to leave just one switch on the lighting circuit it's on?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch

I have two sets of lights in my kitchen. At one end of the kitchen, I have a 2 Gang light switch which operates both sets of lights, and at the other end I have a single light switch which operates the lights at that end of the kitchen. I want to eliminate the single gang light switch totally so it just leaves the 2 gang light switch to control both sets of  lights.

How do I do that?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that one of the switches at the "2 Gang" location and the "single gang" switch at the other location both operate one of the sets of lights, as in a 3-way switch circuit?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: I would suggest you create a diagram showing what you have and what you want. Describing this stuff in words is really hard and I can't make sense of it after reading everything here.

Answer (score 18):

Your circuit contains two 3-way switches. Referring to the diagram below:

- if the switch **with** the incoming "hot" is the one you want single control from (shown at left)-

1) replace that switch with a single-pole switch

2) connect either of the "traveler" wires to the load side

3) remove the other (unwanted) switch and connect the traveler wire used in step-2 to the "switched hot" wire that goes to the lights.

4) the unused "traveler" wire is abandoned

[image]

- If the switch **without** the incoming "hot" is the one you want single control from (shown at right)-

1) remove the switch with the incoming hot (shown at left) and connect the incoming hot to either of the "traveler" wires

2) replace the other switch (shown at right) with a single-pole switch

3) connect the "traveler" wire used in step 1 to one side of the switch

4) connect the "switched hot" that goes to the lights to the other side of the switch.

5) the unused "traveler" wire is abandoned

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply, but you have lost me,

Comment: yeah, 3-way circuits are a bit complicated for layperson. Probably good time to call experienced and reputable electrician.

Comment: I have a double switch which operates 2 lights ( 1 at each end of the kitchen ) the wires that go in the back of the switch are L1 top - Black wire with red band. Com middle - red Wire that is 1 switch , the 2nd Switch has L1 - Blue Wire with a red band, com middle - yelo wire with a red band and L2 has a red wire. the single switch at the other end of the kitchen only operates the light at that end, the wires that go in the back of this switch 2 x red in L2 1 x Black and 1 x blue both with red bands in L1 and yelo wire with red band in com is this description of any help

Comment: its the single switch that I want to do away with and turn the double switch into a single switch so I need to know what wires to use and where they go to change the double to a single and that we also do away with the single switch at the other end of the kitchen

Comment: if anyone else can help ?

Comment: I will venture to say that no one will be able to tell you what to do based on your description. You will need to test (yes, a tester will be required) to determine which lead is your "mains" hot. Then you will be able to determine which leads are the "traveler" leads and the switched hot to the light with further testing/troubleshooting. It would be relatively safe to assume the switches with 3 wire ports in use are the 3-way switches.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the double pole with a single. Cap the red on both ends, keep the white and black attached as normal on the remaining switch, and tie the black and white together on the removed switch.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I edited out all the spurious commentary; if you want to answer a question, please just answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Paul's response. Since everyone else's is so dang complicated. But his was lacking enough detail.

**Step  1:** Remove the 3-way switch from the junction you want to remain and (Assuming this is the hot source) replace the switch with a single pole switch. (continued on step 2)

*Knowledge 1:* 3-way switches only have 1 hot (the black). Then two wires that run through to a second switch to the circuit that are called travelers.

*Knowledge 2:* At the power source switch, the whites are tied together and capped. Leave them like that.

**Step 2:** Place the black into one of the hot poles (gold)

**Step 3:** Identify the traveler (white or red) and attach it to the other hot pole. (mine was red)

**Step 4:** On 3 way switch being removed, take the chosen traveler (mine was red). tie it together with the power traveler (mine was black)

*Knowledge 3:* You can trial and error what you tie together as long as you make sure the power on the input. Is seperately attached.